# Mapping a nested object as an observable from a complex JSON using the create callback

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've got a complex object in a JSON format. I'm using Knockout Mapping, customizing the `create` callback, and trying to make sure that every object that should be an observable - would actually be mapped as such.

The following code is an example of what I've got:
It enables the user to add `cartItems`, save them (as a JSON), empty the cart, and then load the saved items.

The loading part fails: It doesn't display the loaded option (i.e., the loaded `cartItemName`). I guess it's related to some mismatch between the objects in the options list and the object bounded as the `cartItemName` (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488571/selected-option-is-not-updated-when-observable-updates-though-optionsvalue-does/50491725#50491725)), but I can't figure it out.

Code ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebmv22dc/1)):

```js
var cartItemsAsJson = "";
var handlerVM = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.cartItems = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.availableProducts = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.language = ko.observable();
  self.init = function () {
    self.initProducts();
    self.language("english");
  }
  self.initProducts = function () {
    self.availableProducts.push(
      new productVM("Shelf", ['White', 'Brown']),
      new productVM("Door", ['Green', 'Blue', 'Pink']),
      new productVM("Window", ['Red', 'Orange'])
    );
  }
  self.getProducts = function () {
    return self.availableProducts;
  }
  self.getProductName = function (product) {
    if (product) {
      return self.language() == "english" ? 
        product.productName().english : product.productName().french;
    }
  }
  self.getProductValue = function (selectedProduct) {
    // if not caption
    if (selectedProduct) {
      var matched = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.availableProducts(), function (product) {
        return product.productName().english == selectedProduct.productName().english;
      });
      return matched;
    }
  }
  self.getProductColours = function (selectedProduct) {
    selectedProduct = selectedProduct();
    if (selectedProduct) {
      return selectedProduct.availableColours();
    }
  }
  self.addCartItem = function () {
    self.cartItems.push(new cartItemVM());
  }
  self.emptyCart = function () {
    self.cartItems([]);
  }
  self.saveCart = function () {
    cartItemsAsJson = ko.toJSON(self.cartItems);
    console.log(cartItemsAsJson);
  }
  self.loadCart = function () {
    var loadedCartItems = ko.mapping.fromJSON(cartItemsAsJson, {
      create: function(options) {
        return new cartItemVM(options.data);
      }
    });
    self.cartItems(loadedCartItems());
  }
}

var productVM = function (name, availableColours, data) {
  var self = this;
  self.productName = ko.observable({ english: name, french: name + "eux" });
  self.availableColours = ko.observableArray(availableColours);
}
var cartItemVM = function (data) {
  var self = this;
  self.cartItemName = data ?
     ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(data.cartItemName)) :
     ko.observable();
  self.cartItemColour = data ?
     ko.observable(data.cartItemColour) :
     ko.observable();
}
var handler = new handlerVM();
handler.init();
ko.applyBindings(handler);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.js
"></script>
<div>
  <div data-bind="foreach: cartItems">
    <div>
      <select data-bind="options: $parent.getProducts(),
                optionsText: function (item) { return $parent.getProductName(item); },
                optionsValue: function (item) { return $parent.getProductValue(item); }, 
                optionsCaption: 'Choose a product',
                value: cartItemName"
      >
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <select data-bind="options: $parent.getProductColours(cartItemName),
                optionsText: $data,
                optionsCaption: 'Choose a colour',
                value: cartItemColour,
                visible: cartItemName() != undefined"
      >
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button data-bind="text: 'add cart item', click: addCartItem" />
    <button data-bind="text: 'empty cart', click: emptyCart" />
    <button data-bind="text: 'save cart', click: saveCart" />
    <button data-bind="text: 'load cart', click: loadCart" />
  </div>
</div>
```

What needs to be changed to fix it?

P.S.: I've got another piece of code (see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pbm50ud5/1/)) that demonstrates a persistance of the selected value even after changing the options - though there `optionsValue` is a simple string, while here it's an object.

**EDIT:**

I figured out the problem: the call `ko.mapping.fromJS(data.cartItemName)` creates a new `productVM` object, which is not one of the objects inside `availableProducts` array. As a result, none of the options corresponds to the `productVM` contained in the loaded `cartItemName`, so Knockout thereby clears the value altogether and passes `undefined`.

But the question remains: how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the transition from `ViewModel -> plain object -> ViewModel` you loose the relation between the products in your cart and the ones in your `handlerVM`.

A common solution is to, when loading a plain object, manually search for the existing viewmodels and reference those instead. I.e.:

- We create a new `cartItemVM` from the plain object
- Inside its `cartItemName`, there's an object that does not exist in `handlerVM`.
- We look in `handlerVM` for a product that *resembles* this object, and replace the object by the one we find.

In code, inside `loadCart`, before setting the new viewmodels:

```
loadedCartItems().forEach(
    ci => {
      // Find out which product we have:
      const newProduct = ci.cartItemName().productName;
      const linkedProduct = self.availableProducts()
          .find(p => p.productName().english === newProduct.english());

      // Replace the newProduct by the one that is in `handlerVM`
      ci.cartItemName(linkedProduct)
    }
)
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7z6010jz/

As you can see, the equality comparison is kind of ugly. We look for the `english` product name and use it to determine the match. You can also see there's a difference in what is observable and what isn't.

My advice would be to use unique `id` properties for your product, and start using those. You can create a simpler `optionsValue` binding and matching new and old values happens automatically. If you like, I can show you an example of this refactor as well. Let me know if that'd help.

Comment: Thanks. I certainly am interested to see your refactoring. I updated [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z6010jz/1/) with what I thought you had in mind. Is it?